# Detect if img tag inside in span on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever i click on span i want to detect whether i conatins img tag or  tag.
How can i do this.

```
<span class="scorecount" id="6" onclick="javascript:changethevalue(this)">
<img src="images/lock.png" width="25px" height="25px">
</span>

<span class="scorecount" id="6" onclick="javascript:changethevalue(this)">
 4
</span>

function changethevalue(object) {
     console.log($(object).children('img'));
}
```

output is when i click on img

[img, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: span#4.scorecount, selector: "img", constructor: function, init: function…]

on 4 it is
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: span#2.scorecount, selector: "img", constructor: function, init: function…]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/), if the `length` is zero then it means that there is no img tag in descendants of `object`.

```
console.log($(object).has('img').length);
```